# How to find the element for the filter button using Selenium WebDriver for IE and Python:

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm newish to StackOverflow, and programming in general.

I am automating my company's billing system (which only works on IE) using Selenium, and I need to press a Filter button in order to display on the page what our database says. I have tried many variations of xpath in order to find the element, but nothing seems to have worked. Here is the HTML line for the Filter button:

```
<input style="background:green;color:white;" type=button class=bttn onclick="form1.formfilter.value='1';form1.submit();" value="FILTER">
```

Is there a way to find this element by `value="FILTER"`?

I have read the docs and looked for this answer, but I haven't found it, or I'm just not searching the right keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on <kbd>FILTER</kbd> button using the attribute `value="FILTER"` you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.bttn[value='FILTER']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='bttn' and @value='FILTER']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I realized later that the code I had already written for the Filter button press was working, but your suggestion to use WebDriverWait solves another issue I have where the program runs faster than IE loads. I had been solving it with time.sleep(), but then if the internet is slow, the program still runs faster than IE. Now I can use WebDriverWait to make sure the page is loaded and ready before the program moves on.